# Outputted pdf not filling with the content in iTextsharp and C#.net, creating with Zero bytes

Tags: c#, itext

I am working to replace the specific word inside pdf document using iTextSharp and C#.net, while I am debugging getting the proper value but the outputted pdf getting zero bytes(empty),its not filling with the content.

```
ReplacePDFText("Mumbai",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase,Application.StartupPath + "\\test.pdf","D:\\test_words_replaced.pdf"); //Do Everything

public void ReplacePDFText(string strSearch, StringComparison scCase, string strSource, string strDest)
    {

        PdfStamper psStamp = null; //PDF Stamper Object
        PdfContentByte pcbContent = null; //Read PDF Content

        if (File.Exists(strSource)) //Check If File Exists
        {

            PdfReader pdfFileReader = new PdfReader(strSource); //Read Our File

            psStamp = new PdfStamper(pdfFileReader, new FileStream(strDest, FileMode.Create)); //Read Underlying Content of PDF File

            pbProgress.Value = 0; //Set Progressbar Minimum Value
            pbProgress.Maximum = pdfFileReader.NumberOfPages; //Set Progressbar Maximum Value

            for (int intCurrPage = 1; intCurrPage <= pdfFileReader.NumberOfPages; intCurrPage++) //Loop Through All Pages
            {

                LocTextExtractionStrategy lteStrategy = new LocTextExtractionStrategy(); //Read PDF File Content Blocks

                pcbContent = psStamp.GetUnderContent(intCurrPage); //Look At Current Block

                //Determine Spacing of Block To See If It Matches Our Search String
                lteStrategy.UndercontentCharacterSpacing = pcbContent.CharacterSpacing;
                lteStrategy.UndercontentHorizontalScaling = pcbContent.HorizontalScaling;

                //Trigger The Block Reading Process
                string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfFileReader, intCurrPage, lteStrategy);

                //Determine Match(es)
                List<iTextSharp.text.Rectangle> lstMatches = lteStrategy.GetTextLocations(strSearch, scCase);

                PdfLayer pdLayer = default(PdfLayer); //Create New Layer
                pdLayer = new PdfLayer("Overrite", psStamp.Writer); //Enable Overwriting Capabilities

                //Set Fill Colour Of Replacing Layer
                pcbContent.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);

                foreach (iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rctRect in lstMatches) //Loop Through Each Match
                {

                    pcbContent.Rectangle(rctRect.Left, rctRect.Bottom, rctRect.Width, rctRect.Height); //Create New Rectangle For Replacing Layer

                    pcbContent.Fill(); //Fill With Colour Specified

                    pcbContent.BeginLayer(pdLayer); //Create Layer

                    pcbContent.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK); //Fill aLyer

                    pcbContent.Fill(); //Fill Underlying Content

                    PdfGState pgState = default(PdfGState); //Create GState Object
                    pgState = new PdfGState();

                    pcbContent.SetGState(pgState); //Set Current State

                    pcbContent.SetColorFill(BaseColor.WHITE); //Fill Letters

                    pcbContent.BeginText(); //Start Text Replace Procedure

                    pcbContent.SetTextMatrix(rctRect.Left, rctRect.Bottom); //Get Text Location

                    //Set New Font And Size
                    pcbContent.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 9);

                    pcbContent.ShowText("AMAZING!!!!"); //Replacing Text

                    pcbContent.EndText(); //Stop Text Replace Procedure

                    pcbContent.EndLayer(); //Stop Layer replace rocedure

                }                   
                pbProgress.Value++; //Increase Progressbar Value

                pdfFileReader.Close(); //Close File                 
            }

            //psStamp.Close(); //Close Stamp Object             
        }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You call

```
pdfFileReader.Close();
```

much too early: inside a loop in which the next iteration still requires `pdfFileReader` and furthermore before closing the stamper.

The stamper requires the `PdfReader` to still be open when the stamper closes because it copies certain parts of the reader only then.